# Re-using parameters in Ole DB?

Tags: sql, db2, oledb

I'm writing an Ole DB command and I need to repeat one particular parameter. Basically the situation is that I can't control the parameters that are passed in (this is handled by a (horrible) framework) and I can not create a stored procedure.

The query looks something like

```
DELETE FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyId = ? ;

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (MyId, SomeValue, SomeOtherValue) 
VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Problem is that the framework will only ever pass in the values for MyId, SomeValue and SomeOtherValue (in that order). Is there some way I can "use" that MyId value in the delete and still be able to access it again for the insert?

The backing DB is IBM DB2 if it's relevant.

Comment: So you're saying you can't alter the SQL that it uses nor can you double up the parameters as needed?

Comment: I can modify the query but not the parameters that are passed in. I also can't replace the query with a stored proc. And I definitely can not change to an ADO.NET provider :) Working under rather constrained conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for OLE DB connections, the ? maps to one parameter only once. That's one of the advantages of using the ADO.NET provider is that it uses named parameters.

Since you state you can modify the query, then it should be easy, just mix and match. Use the OLE DB parameters to assign to a local variable like so

```
DECLARE @MyId int
SET @MyId = ?
DELETE FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyId = @myid ;

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (MyId, SomeValue, SomeOtherValue) 
VALUES (@myId,?,?)
```

I don't have a DB2 instance any more or I'd very it works but it ought to...